# Randomization Testing help

Tags: bootstrap, monte-carlo, permutation-test

I am scratching my head over this one...any help would be greatly appreciated.

I want to know if the average travel time between Guell Park and the beach in Barcelona using the bus or the metro differ and which one is faster. Since I do not know the distribution of travel time, I can't use a t-test; therefore, I was suggested to use a randomization test (so I don't make any assumptions about the data).

Here are the data:
Metro (in min): 34, 39, 28, 42, 32, 37, 41, 40, 47, 36, 38, 48, 31 
Bus (in min): 40, 44, 49, 50, 48, 45, 47, 46, 39, 55

How would I go about proving there is or is not a different between the forms of transportation (randomization tests)?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Jay. Did you probably mean permutation test?

Comment: From what I have been told, yes, permutation (monte-carlo). I have been trying to figure it out in R, but I am at the point where my eyes are melting.

Comment: Your data present no problem for a t-test.  It is likely the very best choice for comparing average travel times. But the difference is so clear, almost any appropriate test will be significant.